# "Get Outlook Mail Messages: The specified folder does not exist" error in UiPath Studio debugging

Tags: uipath-studio

I have just started learning UiPath and currently completing their online beginner level training.
In the Get Outlook Mail Messages process I put everything correctly and yet get this "Get Outlook Mail Messages: The specified folder does not exist" error.

I tried the following things but no success

1. Setting MailFolder as "Inbox"
2. Specifying the Account name and them setting the MailFolder to "Inbox"
3. Specifying the entire folder path in the MailFolder section
4. Increasing the timeout
5. Closing and reopening both Outlook and UiPath Studio
   I have tried almost all the remedies to this problem yet the process is not running.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.